# How to display dynamic column in angular dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to display dropdown options depending on the value I pass in controller

Controller:

```
This.selectedColumn = label;

This.dditems = [
    {
        id: 1,
        label: 'aLabel',
        subItem: 'aSubItem'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        label: 'bLabel',
        subItem: 'bSubItem'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        label: 'bLabel',
        subItem: 'cSubItem'
    }
];
```

In above code I have selectedColumn as label, then I should display `dditems.label` in dropdown. If I pass `selectedColumn` as `subItem`, then I should display `dditems.subItem` in dropdown.

Html:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button" >
    <li role="menuitem" data-ng-repeat="item in dc.dditems">
       <a>{{ item.label }}</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

In above code I have hardcoded `item.label`, so now item.label column is displaying. But I want to display value based on `selectedColumn`.

Eg: `<a>{{ item.selectedColumn }}</a>`

How can I do this dynamic way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've have a made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsalaat/bTyAa/15/) for your solution. You can change the click event with any event you want your repeat property to change.

According to your code you just have to change the `selectedColumn` variable with any event.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button" >
    <li role="menuitem" data-ng-repeat="item in dc.dditems">
       <a>{{ item[selectedColumn] }}</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Hope it helps